# Using Xamarin Forms, Should i use push notification or web socket for real time communication?

Tags: android, ios, websocket, xamarin.forms, push-notification

**Background:**

There are two Apps I am currently building in Xamarin Forms IOS/Android.

1. CustomerApp
2. PartnerApp

CustomerApp scans Qr code from partner app and submits API request using Aws API gateway, lambda and node js once request successful sends Sns to do multiple operations in the background.

**Question:**

I want to utilize Sns and send a notification to PartnerApp which would display the result on partner app, to determine the request from customer app has been successful or declined.

How can I achieve this architecture?

1. Using apple/google push notification service?
2. Using Web sockets to make Customer App as client and Partner App as a server? However, using this how can I resolve challenges for mobile networks and their dynamic IP addresses?
3. Another way to achieve this?

[image: arch]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not really clear...
Just implement a traditional architecture.

For instance:

- Scan your code then call WebApiMethod A: to send the QRcode on your server (with parameters like client 'ID', the QRCode ...)
- Server can now: notify your customerAPP that a new QRCode is available
- Server can make some computation THEN send a push Notification to the client APP when its finished.

I don't know if you already have a dedicated server or not, but

- server side computation (cloud methods)
- and sending push notifications

can be achieve with MS AZURE, AWS, or other services like PARSE and more...
Hope it can give you some clues...